# scroll webpage using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to scroll a webpage upto a certain length I am trying to scroll the webpage with this line of code

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

It is executing very well but this code scroll the webpage till last. But I want to scroll till 90% of the page. Any idea how to approach this kind of problem. A little advice will also be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i think it's `(document.body.scrollHeight)*90/100`.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/INVENTORY/shopperstop/attempt_two.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")*90/100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'` this error will be shown